# Convert rgb array to string

Tags: php

I want to convert

```
array("r" => "144", "g" => "24", "b" => "26")
```

to

```
"144, 24, 26"
```

I've tried using array_map with strval but it doesn't work.

```
array_map('strval', $array)
```

I dont know exactly why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `implode()`

```
$arr = array("r" => "144", "g" => "24", "b" => "26");
$str = implode(', ',$arr);
// If you want a double quote around string, add following line:
echo '"' . $str . '"';
```

[Working Code:](https://3v4l.org/IOVmh)

Comment: When you see a commonly asked question you should close it as a duplicate instead of answering it.

Comment: @JohnConde, I will definitely do it from now.

Comment: Thanks. I used ```implode(', ', $arr)```